# Trying to get bold italic math with Lucida OT and unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, lucida

I am using the Lucida Bright OT fonts. For various reasons -- yes, I know it is not the usual thing to do -- I need to have the variables in the following MWE in * bold italics*, not **upright bold**:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}
\setmathfontface{\mathBold}{Lucida Bright Math OT Demibold}

\begin{document}

$E=mc^2+\beta$ and $\mathBold{E=mc^2+\beta}$ and $\mathBold{xy^2}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Upright not italic bold.]

Thus far I have found no combination of TeX/unicode-math incantations that will cause the bold variables to be rendered in bold italics.

I know it is odd, but is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4):

A variable in bold face math italic is obtained with `\symbfit`:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\begin{document}

$E=mc^2+\beta$ and $\symbfit{E}=\symbfit{m}\symbfit{c}^2+\symbfit{\beta}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a formula where *everything* is emboldened:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}
\setmathfont[version=bold]{Lucida Bright Math OT Demibold}

\begin{document}

$E=mc^2+\beta$ and {\boldmath$E=mc^2+\beta$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks -- back to the documentation.