# How to select a font for math mode, when the font encompasses several .otf files?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, unicode-math

According to section 3 *Getting Started* on p. 4 of the `unicode-math` package documentation for the user version 2020/01/31 0.8q (which is the current version), here's an example using the filename syntax to load the TeX Gyre Pagella Math font:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
```

What if a math font encompasses several `.otf` files? For instance, the [STIX Two font](https://www.stixfonts.org/) encompasses 5 `.otf` files:

- *STIX2Math.otf*
- *STIX2Text-Regular.otf*
- *STIX2Text-Bold.otf*
- *STIX2Text-Italic.otf*
- *STIX2Text-BoldItalic.otf*.

How can I configure the document to use this font in math mode? (And only in math mode.)

Or should I be concerned only with *STIX2Math.otf* if I want to use the STIX font only in math mode, because the other files are intended for use in text mode? But maybe the *STIX2Text-....otf* files are meant for typesetting variables in math mode, in which case they are indispensable.

P.S. I use LuaLaTeX as my LaTeX compiler.

Comment: just use stix2math the others are text fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is this the usual case, that OpenType fonts meant to be used in math mode comprise only a single `.otf` file? Or do some popular fonts require several files? In the latter case, I'll appreciate a general answer, and not just one that pertains to STIX Two.

Comment: You should choose your text font from `fontspec` or `polyglossia` or `babel` and should be just `STIX Two Text` and then from `unicode-math` you should choose your math font eg `STIX Two Math`. The math font contains mathematical symbols which text font doesn't eg the Integral, or the partial derivative symbols. Just take care the text font you should choose and the math font match each other.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I load only *STIX2Math.otf*, where will the glyphs for math-mode variables and text embedded in formulas be retrieved from? Or does *STIX2Math.otf* supply glyphs for variables and text within formulas too? For instance, all the alphabetical symbols listed in chapter 13 of the [`unicode-math` list of symbols](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) (starting on p. 71). Which STIX Two `.otf` file needs to be loaded to be able to use them?

Comment: The text parts inside math uses the text font, so you should combine a text and a math fonts that work well together. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286329/52406) you find a way to set up Lucida, that comes with a (not so complete) bold math font (six years old, but I guess it still applies).

Comment: Variables are in the math font too, for text you switch to text mode and then it depends how you did set up the text fonts with fontspec.

Comment: it is exactly the same as the tex gyre pagella example you show, you just used the math font and did not list all the tex gyre pagella textfonts. Why do you think stix is different?

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in using both the text and math fonts of the Stix Two font *family*, you could execute (under LuaLaTeX)

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text} % access STIX2Text-Regular.otf, STIX2Text-Bold.otf, 
                            %   STIX2Text-Italic.otf, and STIX2Text-BoldItalic.otf.
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math} % access STIX2Math.otf
```

Nothing more to it.

Of course, if you prefer to refer to the font file names directly, you are free to do so.

Comment: Hope it will supports `XeLaTeX` too!!

Comment: @GowriSaro - Assuming the font files are present on your system, the exact form of the arguments of `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont` may differ between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, depending mainly on which operating system and which TeX distribution you employ -- of which I'm afraid I have no knowledge... That's why I limited my answer to the LuaLaTeX case.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, I'm always not well in English, if my sentence hurts you, humble excuse, please. I'm also new to `LaTeX` and I'm very new to XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, so only I confirmed with you regarding the usage of `XeLaTeX`, again please excuse me, normally I'm using `LaTeX` and `PDFLaTeX` oftenly

Comment: You people are like  `Guru` for beginners like me

Comment: @GowriSaro - So glad we're all ok. I've gone ahead and deleted one of my earlier comments.

Comment: It's my pleasure, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks. You started your answer with: "If you're interested in using both the text and math fonts of the Stix Two font family". Does this imply that if I'm interested in using only the text or only the math fonts of this family, then I can't use the relevant parts of your code; only if I'm interested in using both?

Comment: @EvanAad - Absolutely not. If you're interested solely in the Stix Two text fonts, you'd use just the `\setmainfont` directive. (You wouldn't want to use either `\setsansfont` or `\setmonofont`, though, as `Stix Two` is neither a sans-serif nor a monospaced font. Well, if you like to run the risk of needlessly and hopelessly confusing yourself...) If you're interested solely in the Stix Two math font, you'd use just the `\setmathfont` directive. Finally (cumulatively?), if you're interested in both the Stix Two text and Stix Two math fonts, you'd use both `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont`.

Comment: Does this trick work only with STIX Two, or with other math fonts as well? And how can I tell for each font how to name it in the `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont` commands? (For instance, how did you know to write `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}` rather than, say, `\setmathfont{STIXTwo Math}`, or `\setmathfont{STIX2 Math}`?

Comment: @EvanAad - Not sure why you call it a "trick". For conventions on how to use abstract versus literal names of files, please consult the user guide of the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.